# Given a current list node how do I insert an item, x, correctly after the node referenced by current?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

The question is given a current (a reference to a list node), which statement may insert an item x correctly after the node referenced by current?

My options are:

```
a. current = new ListNode(x, current);
b. current.next = new ListNode( x, current.next);
c. current.next() = new ListNode(x, current);
d. current.next() = new ListNode(x, current.next);
e. current = new ListNode(x, current.next);
f. current.next = new ListNode ( x, current);
g. none of the above.
```

I believe the right answer is b because it is referencing current.next and placing x in the current.next position. Please let me know if you think my answer is correct.

Comment: Why don't you try out your answer yourself and check?

Comment: This feels pretty much like a homework assignment or similar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, answer choice b is correct. 
The line:

```
current.next = new ListNode( x, current.next);
```

tells the current node to point to the new `ListNode` being created. The new node will first, via its constructor, point to `current.next`. The first node will thus point to the new node (which already points to the node that was previously after current) and be inserted correctly. Parentheses are not needed in current.next since `next` is an instance variable in the `ListNode` class rather than a method.

Comment: Hi Justin and welcome to the community. I think you could even expand the "parentheses are not needed" to something stronger, like "parentheses must not be used" in this case, since trying to do `node.next() = foo` is invalid in Java. Simply put, a method call is not a valid lvalue in a statement.